# Инициализация массива ArrayList-ами

Tags: java, generics

```
ArrayList<String>[] lists = {new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<String>()};
```

Почему не работает?

Предлагать варианты с использованием ArrayList-а ArrayList-ов не надо, просто хочу знать, в чем проблема, в интернете гуглил про массивы и generics, не нашел ничего годного.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что так нельзя. [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays):

> "You cannot create arrays of parameterized types"

Но, в принципе, можно схитрить:

```
class MyStringArrayList extends ArrayList<String> { }
```

А потом:

```
MyStringArrayList[] lists = {new MyStringArrayList(), new MyStringArrayList()};
```

Comment: cпасибо, тогда такой вопрос: /* Массив списков строк
Создать массив, элементами которого будут списки строк. Заполнить массив любыми данными и вывести их на экран.
*/
вот задача, че за фигня тогда, почему они задают такую задачу, может есть какой-то альтернативный вариант инициализации массива листами?

Comment: Может в задании под **списком строк** имеется ввиду не `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: а что может иметься в виду под списком строк еще?

Comment: @Maxgmer существуют не только одномерные массивы+что вам мешает создать класс, описывающий необходимые данные и создать массив объектов данного класса?

Comment: @Maxgmer, Это нужно спрашивать у того, кто дал задание. Посмотрите, я там обновил пост.

Comment: мешает то, что нужно работать по задаче внутри одного метода, который возвращает ArrayList<String>[]

Comment: `ArrayList<String>[]` – такого не бывает.

Comment: бывает, я просто инициализировал этот массив не объектами, а ссылками на листы, так всё у меня пошло. Все, всем спасибо, ставлю + за годную ссылку из доков)